# Input String for Thread Class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a subclass of a Thread Class. Every created thread should parse a string , but my class is not designed to get the string from keyboard input because in `public static void main(String[] args)` i should create and run each thread in this way

```
for (int=0;i<how_many_words;i++)

  (new myThread()).start();
```

So app need to know number of string to create threads, so I can not input these strings in Thread class. How can i input these strings and pass to each thread ?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't get the strings from the keyboard.  Can you explain that in your question a bit more.  How about an input file?  Maybe arguments to main?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly, but I assume you need separate thread listening for user input using for example `Scanner` class inside `while(true)` loop and starting a new `Thread` after user input has been collected.

```
Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
df.setLenient(false);

try {
    while (true) {

      String input = scanner.next();
      new MyThread(input).start();
    } 
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by encouraging you NOT to subclass Thread but instead implement Runnable, but that is not really relavent to your question.  If I understand you correctly, all you really want is...

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private final String word;
    public MyThread( String word ) {
        this.word = word;
    }
    public void run() {
        // do something with this.word
    }
}
```

The javadocs for Thread say pretty much the same thing:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

With your main would be something like...

```
String[] splits = input.split( " " );
for(String split : splits ) {
    (new MyThread(split)).start();
}
```

I don't know if the splits thing will work exactly; what are your criteria for word boundaries.  Also, you should probably throttle the number of Threads you want to spawn off here.  I strongly recommend reading Java Concurrency in Practice as you wade into multi-threaded Java.

Comment: I think I like Wojtek O's sample implementation of a main.